# about on_touch_down and on_touch_move

Tags: python, kivy

I want to work with on_touch_down  with a left-click but it just with work right-click and on touch move didn't work with anything

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Color, Line

Window.clearcolor = (47/255, 72/255, 125/255, 1)


class PaintWindow(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        s = 30
        self.canvas.add(Color(rgb=(184/255, 154/255, 200/255)))
        self.canvas.add(Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - s/2, touch.y - s/2), size=(s, s)))
        touch.ud["line"] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))
        self.canvas.add(touch.ud)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud["line"].points += Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))


class PaintApp(App):
    def bulid(self):
        return PaintWindow()
PaintApp().run()
```

how can i fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

You are not seeing the results of your `on_touch_down()` or `on_touch_move()`. Your `PaintApp` has a `bulid()` that probably should be `build()`. Check your spelling.